# Zombie option missing from both diagnostics and instruments

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, nszombie

Running Xcode 4.0.2, the Zombie option is missing, from both places where other SO posts have suggested to find it.

Product > Run... looks like this:
[image]

Product > Profile looks like this:
[image]
[image]

What is strange is that I have used Zombies before in this version of Xcode. I did a profile using the Allocations instrument, clicked Allocations' info button ("i") at the upper left, and checked the "Enable Zombie..." that then appeared there. But when I try that now, I get this:

[image]

No more Zombies. Is it possible that I somehow removed them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around some more, I found the answer here: [zombie question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

Ehud B's answer says you have to use the simulator for iOS apps, not the device. When I switched to the simulator for profiling, the zombies were back.

I should note that Moshe Kravchik's answer indicates that zombies are available in iOS 5. I'm still using iOS 4.

Comment: Does this mean we cannot test zombies on device? I have a device-only crash I have to debug

Comment: You can't test it running iOS 5?