# Unable to find Zombie in Instruments for device

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments

Unable to find Zombie in Instruments for device .

I am able to find Zombie in Instruments for Simulator but not able to find for device , my app only run on device due to addition of third party api.

How can i trace cause of crash due to **`"message sent to deallocated instance "`**

I just want to find exact instance(or line of code) which is causing this crash.

Comment: You cant check zombies in device.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564018/zombie-option-missing-from-both-diagnostics-and-instruments

Comment: but they are saying that i have to use simulator not device but my app  only works on device

Comment: Yes. Use exception break point and try to simulate that crash. Me too felt that kind of issues. But u don't have other option.

Comment: Do u known in which screen its getting crash? in the sense can u simulate the crash ?

Comment: yes i know the screen where app is getting crash

Comment: Fine. How its getting crash? while performing some action or some thing else?

Comment: Include the whole crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Although, when XCode returns "Message sent to deallocated instance" error message, it normally tells the Object as well which is sending that error.
Anyway, you can use the below to find the exact line which is causing you the error:

Use **Exception BreakPoint** for **All Exceptions** in XCode.
 To Add an Exception Breakpoint:
1. Go to BreakPoint Navigator
2. At the bottom there is a plus symbol. Click it.
3. You will get two options: Add Exception Breakpoint... and Add Symbolic BreakPoint...
   Choose Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: i have enabled all exceptions breakpoint but in this case that is not working.

Comment: Some times it may happen. Exception break point cant help in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons for zombies crash:
1. Control delegate response late after the control instance is cleared.
2. Instance used inside the thread try to modify the instance after its get cleared.

So handle the delegate properly

1. Make control delegates to nil while removing view controller like this:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [self.mapView setDelegate:nil];
       [_webView setDelegate:nil];
   }
   ```